# Card View with round corner API 27

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

Below this is my code :

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorSecondary"
    app:cardCornerRadius="250dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customer_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_no_picture" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

It works perfectly with API 30/29/28 but for API 27 i just have an empty CardView. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: how about giving the app:cardBackgroundColor explicit color?

Comment: Thanks for the tips but i've already try with an explicit color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to fix my problem, with API 27 to have circular image with cardView you have to put cardCornerRadius to a maximum of width / height.
In my example i just write `app:cardCornerRadius="39dp"` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries on github which makes Imageview in circular shape. You can explore github.

[Here is the one of its's kind for **CircularImageView**](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Comment: I don't want to use a library, it's just technical debt for a simple thing